# Laptop cannot boot as a result of trying to solve windows BSOD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, boot, partitioning, bsod

So, I have 512GB SSD laptop in which I had windows pre-installed. recently, I installed ubuntu in it for dual boot. Both the OS were working perfectly. Suddenly today I was booting into windows and faced BSOD error. I tried multiple ways to solve the problem but could not. Laptop would go into "Preparing Automatic Repair" and BSOD on the next screen. My Ubuntu was working fine.So I tried to mount the windows partition and EFI partition using "mount" and realized that both the partitions have a similar directory named /EFI and it has the Windows Boot Mgr. So I tried to copy the directory in EFI partition to the windows one. And in doing so I removed the directory in the EFI partition. And now my laptop directly goes to BIOS and doesn't even show any boot menu. I am booting into the system using a bootable Ubuntu flash drive. Doing so, I can see all my partitions perfectly. So, I am quite sure it is not a hardware issue. Can this be solved or do I have to install both the Operating Systems from scratch. Thanks!!

Comment: Never mess up with boot configuration without backup or knowing what you are doing! One way I could think of is to attach the OS disk to another running machine, chroot & rebuild the boot configuration. But, that's what we used to do for Linux machines but for laptop, I've no idea...

Answer (score 2):

If you are lucky and haven't destroyed the boot environment too much,
you should be able to get by without total reinstallation:

- Create a Windows boot media, or use a Windows recovery disk
  (if you have one)
- Repair the Windows boot as described in
  [How to Run a Startup Repair in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)
- This will recreate the EFI partition, but with only boot into Windows
- Use the
  [Rescatux Disk](https://www.supergrubdisk.org/rescatux/)
  to restore Grub and the Linux boot.

If all goes well, you would recover both the Windows and Linux
installations. In the future, it is safer to modify boot data
using a utility, rather than doing dangerous partition modifications
manually.